# Monaco Editor | How to properly use Hover's IMarkdownString with HTML

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

```js
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'mySpecialLanguage' });

monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider('mySpecialLanguage', {
    provideHover: function (model, position) {
        return {
            range: new monaco.Range(
                1,
                1,
                model.getLineCount(),
                model.getLineMaxColumn(model.getLineCount())
            ),
            contents: [
                {
                    supportHtml: true,
                    value: '<div style="color red; class="test">yes</div>'
                }
            ]
        };
    }
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: '\n\nHover over this text',
    language: 'mySpecialLanguage'
});
```

I'm trying to provide a HoverProvider for my editor but I can't seem to render the element with a different foreground or classList, Am I doing something wrong here? It works okay but the style didn't load / inserted to the hover content. I'm using [IMarkdownString](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.IMarkdownString.html)

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108780/how-to-set-font-color-for-hover-message).

Only a subset of HTML tags and attributes are supported in `IMarkdownString`. Only the HTML `span` elememt supports the `style` attribute and the CSS defined in the style attribute needs to align to these specific rules:

- Is only allowed the CSS properties color or background-color
- Must be defined in hex (colour names are not allowed)
- No space between color: and the hex value
- Must contain a semi colon at the end of the hex value

If you change the HTML string defined in the  `value` property to

```
<span style="color:#ff0000;">yes<span>
```

then it should work and display the word "yes" in red.

If you copy and paste the following code into the Monaco playground, you should see it working:

```
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'mySpecialLanguage' });

monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider('mySpecialLanguage', {
    provideHover: function (model, position) {
        return {
            range: new monaco.Range(
                1,
                1,
                model.getLineCount(),
                model.getLineMaxColumn(model.getLineCount())
            ),
            contents: [
                {
                    supportHtml: true,
                    value: '<span style="color:#ff0000;">yes</span>'
                }
            ]
        };
    }
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: '\n\nHover over this text',
    language: 'mySpecialLanguage'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` does not contain a valid HTML. You're missing a colon after `color` and you're not closing the `style` attribute with a quote.
It should be: `'<div style="color: red" class="test">yes</div>'`