# How to set font color for hover message?

Tags: monaco-editor

I use `hoverMessage` to show some message, and want to set the font color with html template. I have set property `supportHtml` to `true`, but it not working.
How can I set the font color for hover message?

[result in demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CRvX.png)

Here are my codes:

```
var jsCode = [
    '"use strict";',
    'function Person(age) {',
    '   if (age) {',
    '       this.age = age;',
    '   }',
    '}',
    'Person.prototype.getAge = function () {',
    '   return this.age;',
    '};'
].join('\n');

var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: jsCode,
    language: 'javascript'
});

var decorations = editor.deltaDecorations(
    [],
    [
        {
            range: new monaco.Range(3, 1, 5, 1),
            options: {
                isWholeLine: true,
                linesDecorationsClassName: 'myLineDecoration'
            }
        },
        {
            range: new monaco.Range(7, 1, 7, 24),
            options: { 
                inlineClassName: 'myInlineDecoration',
                hoverMessage: [{
                    value: '**Error occurs：**'
                }, {
                    // isTrusted: true,
                    // supportHtml: true,
                    value: `<span style="color: red !important">1111111111</span>`
                }, {
                    isTrusted: true,
                    supportHtml: true,
                    value: `<span style="color: yellow !important">22222222222222</span>`
                }]
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This comment](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/801#issuecomment-941791325) suggests that only a subset of HTML is supported in `IMarkdownString`. Looking at the [markdownRenderer code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/6d2920473c6f13759c978dd89104c4270a83422d/src/vs/base/browser/markdownRenderer.ts#L297-L317) you can see that the `style` attribute is only supported in the HTML `span` tag (which is what you're using). Looking further down (lines 308-309), the CSS defined in `style` needs to be a very specific format and align to these rules:

- Is only allowed the CSS properties `color` or `background-color`
- Must be defined in hex (colour names are not allowed)
- No space between `color:` and the hex value
- Must contain a semi colon at the end of the hex value

This explains why this doesn't work:

```
<span style="color: yellow !important">22222222222222</span>
```

but this does:

```
<span style="color:#ffff00;">22222222222222</span>
```

[image: styled text in hover]

If you copy and paste the following code into the [Monaco playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html), you should see it working:

```
var jsCode = [
    '"use strict";',
    'function Person(age) {',
    '   if (age) {',
    '       this.age = age;',
    '   }',
    '}',
    'Person.prototype.getAge = function () {',
    '   return this.age;',
    '};'
].join('\n');

var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: jsCode,
    language: 'javascript'
});

var decorations = editor.deltaDecorations(
    [],
    [
        {
            range: new monaco.Range(3, 1, 5, 1),
            options: {
                isWholeLine: true,
                linesDecorationsClassName: 'myLineDecoration'
            }
        },
        {
            range: new monaco.Range(7, 1, 7, 24),
            options: { 
                inlineClassName: 'myInlineDecoration',
                hoverMessage: [{
                    value: '**Error occurs：**'
                }, {
                    isTrusted: true,
                    supportHtml: true,
                    value: `<span style="color:#ff0000;">1111111111</span>`
                }, {
                    isTrusted: true,
                    supportHtml: true,
                    value: `<span style="color:#ffff00;">22222222222222</span>`
                }]
            }
        }
    ]
);
```